# Distinguishing identifiers from common strings

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I want to write a parser using `Bison/Yacc` + `Lex` which can parse statements like:

```
VARIABLE_ID = 'STRING'
```

where:

```
ID       [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

and:

```
STRING      [a-zA-Z0-9_]+
```

So, `var1 = '123abc'` is a valid statement while `1var = '123abc'` isn't.

Therefore, a `VARIABLE_ID` is a `STRING` but a `STRING` not always is a `VARIABLE_ID`.

What I would like to know is if the only way to distinguish between the two is writing a checking procedure at a higher level (i.e. inside `Bison` code) or if I can work it out in the `Lex` code.

Comment: Aren't your strings always surrounded by single-quotes, as you have written them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your abstract statement syntax is actually:

```
VARIABLE = STRING
```

and not

```
VARIABLE = 'STRING'
```

because the quote delimiters are a lexical detail that we generally want to keep out of the syntax.  And so, the token patterns are actually this:

```
ID       [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
STRING   '[a-zA-Z_0-9]*'
```

An `ID` is a letter or underscore, followed by any combination (including empty) of letters, digits and underscores.

A `STRING` is a single quote, followed by a sequence (possibly empty) letters, digits and underscores, followed by another single quote.

So the ambiguity you are concerned about does not exist. An `ID` is not in fact a `STRING`, nor vice versa.

Somewhere inside your Bison parser, or possibly in the lexer, you might want to massage the `yytext` of a `STRING` match to remove the quotes and just retain the text in between them as a string. This could be a Bison rule, possibly similar to:

```
string : STRING 
       {
          $$ = strip_quotes($1);
       }
       ;
```