# How to distinguish identifier and string?

Tags: bison, lex

I have a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19249397/distinguishing-identifiers-from-common-strings), but with a little difference. I want to parse the pattern below:

```
ID = STRING
```

Note STRING has no quotation. The difference between ID and STRING is ID can only start with char and underline, STRING has no such constraint. Where is the better place to distinguish identifier and string, flex or bison?

Comment: That's a job for flex.

Comment: You're making life difficult for yourself. There's a reason strings are normally in quotes; it makes life easier. If `a_97 = a_97` needs to treat the first as an ID and the second as a STRING, you have to have context-sensitive lexing with semantic feedback from the parser. You could decide instead to allow `STRING = STRING` and impose a semantic check that the string on the LHS should be an ID; that should make life a bit easier (but beware ambiguous grammars). You might prefer to create a rule: `id : STRING` which checks that the string is a valid identifier, and use `id = STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

In flex, if the input matches two patterns, the first pattern will be preferred. So you can write, for example:

```
[[:alpha:]]_[[:alnum:]_]+   { yylval = strdup(yytext); return ID; }
[[:alnum:]_]+               { yylval = strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
```

and the first rule will be executed for inputs like `a_97` (which both patterns match) while the second one will be executed for inputs like `97_a` (which the first pattern doesn't match).

Answer (score 1):

Take `a_97 = a_97` as an example. The problem is that I will get the token sequence: ID, '=', ID, which is not acceptable by the syntax rule `ID = STRING`. I decide to treat them as STRING, and leave the check on the Bison side.